# How can I walk up along the AST using IDAPython decompiler API?

Tags: ida, idapython, hexrays

I am using IDAPython for my analysis. In IDA v6.95, the header file `plugins/hexrays_sdk/include/hexrays.hpp` defines the following:

```
typedef ctree_items_t parents_t;

parents_t parents;      ///< Vector of parents of the current item

/// Get parent of the current item as an expression
cexpr_t *parent_expr(void) { return (cexpr_t *)parents.back(); }

// Get parent of the current item as a statement
cinsn_t *parent_insn(void) { return (cinsn_t *)parents.back(); }
```

For my analysis, I am trying to walk up along the parents from a given `cexpr_t` node. `parent_expr()` and `parent_insn()` API gives me back the immediate parent, not the entire chain from the child to root of the AST.

As an alternative, I tried to traverse the `parents` vector once I visit the given `cexpr_t` node.

```
for parent in reversed(self.parents):
  print "|==> %s [%d]" % (hex(parent.ea), parent.op)
```

The problem is, the `parent` item thus returned is of type `citem_t`. If I cast those to `cexpr_t` as follows:

```
parent.__class__ = cexpr_t
print parent.x
```

and access any of its fields (e.g. `x`) in the example above, it throws error.

How can I traverse the AST nodes bottom-up yet retaining the correct types (`cexpr_t` or `cinsn_t`) of respective nodes? Is it possible to look into the code of `parent_expr()` or `parent_insn()` to see if how do those return correctly typed nodes from an `ctree_items_t` type vector (i.e. `parents`)? The code inside `python/ida_hexrays.py` seems to be mere SWIG stub, the actual implementation seems to lie somewhere else.

```
def parent_expr(self, *args):
    """
    parent_expr(self) -> cexpr_t
    """
    return _ida_hexrays.ctree_visitor_t_parent_expr(self, *args)

def parent_insn(self, *args):
    """
    parent_insn(self) -> cinsn_t
    """
    return _ida_hexrays.ctree_visitor_t_parent_insn(self, *args)
```

The actual code seems to be distributed as a shared library located at `python/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/[ida32|ida64]/_ida_hexrays.so`

Answer (score 1):

I can solve part of your problem.  Use the 'to_specific_type' attribute to convert a citem to a cexpr:

```
if citem.is_expr():
    cexpr = citem.to_specific_type
```